# How to configure second router so that both have access to all resouces

Tags: networking

I have three routers, and a hub,and a server, and I am trying to get them all to talk to each other. I had previously configured them all to do so, but the wires have all been plugged in different ports, and configuration been messed up. I know it is possible with this hardware (because I used to have it working), but I can't remember how I did it (actually I remember clearly, but now it appears not to work, so I doubt myself).

Scenario

```
Main_Router: 192.168.1.1 / 255.255.255.0
ADSL_Router: 192.168.2.1 / 255.255.255.0
Server:      192.168.1.15 / 255.255/255.0
Second_Router: 192.168.0.1 / 255.255.0.0 <~ problem

       RJ11         WAN          LAN  
Internet->ADSL_Router->Main_Router->Hub->Server
```

This part all works... so the internet comes in via phone line, connects to ADSL router, which is then connected to the the Main router's WAN port. The Main router, then connects to the Hub via the LAN port.

The main router gives out IP addresses in the range 192.168.1.20-99, and sets the

The part that is not working, is the Second_Router, which allows people to connect to it, giving them an address on it's subnet (192.168.0.100-200), does share the internet if I plug it into a spare LAN port on the ADS_Router, but fails to allow connections to the Server (or the other router). If I connect it to the HUB, it does not do anything useful at all.

There seems to be no `Access Point` mode on the second router, so that option is not possible.

If any more information is required, I am happy to post here.

Can someone point me in the right direction to get anyone connected to either wifi router to have access to both the Server, and the Internet?

I have access to configure the two wifi routers, but not the ADSL router.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're missing the static route to your LAN segment. To fix that:

- Add a static route on your ADSL router that declares the LAN subnet and forwards the traffic to the external leg of your main router
- Make sure that the SNAT rules on your ADSL router will handle the internal subnet as well. That's usually either automatic or very easy to add.

Without knowledge of what hardware and software you're using, it's difficult to give you more precise answer.

Comment: I can not configure the ADSL router - that is done by external telecoms company I can not communicate with. Is there any way for me to detect the settings they have used?

Comment: Also, if you remove the ADSL box from the equation, I still can't get the second router to recognize the Server. I think if I solve that issue, the rest will fall into place, as that is how it was working before.

Comment: It's not a question of detecting these settings, it's a question of being able to add the route. Also, I had a second look at the settings you posted and they don't make sense: your second router has an incorrect subnet mask and seems to have only one IP address. The basic definition os a router is a computer system that will route packets between different segments. Obviously, with just one interface, it's not going to be able to do that.